# Deserializing ArrayList<Interface> using GSON

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization, gson

I have a class **`Shop`**

```
public class Shop {

  private String name;
  private ArrayList<Fruitable> fruits;


  public String toJson() {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     return gson.toJson(this, Shop.class) 
  }   

}
```

**`Apple`** and **`Orange`** are the two classes that implements **`Fruitable`** interface.

**`Fruitable`:**

```
public interface Fruitable {
   String getColor();
}
```

**`Apple`:**

```
public class Apple implements Fruitable {

 private int Id;     

 @Override
 public String getColor() {
    return "red";
  }

 }
```

**`Orange`:**

```
 public class Orange implements Fruitable {

 private int Id;

 @Override
 public String getColor() {
    return "orange";
  }

 }
```

I can serialize **`Shop`** using GSON, however, I cannot deserialize it properly.

When I deserialize, the `ArrayList<Fruitable>` has objects, but the objects are `null`.

This is because GSON requires a concrete instance to deserialze into.

I know I can implement **`JsonDeserializer`** in **`Shop`**.

However, can I implement some deserializing mechanism, inside **`Apple`** and **`Orange`**  so they will deserialize themselves?

If that is not possible, and I have to write a deserializer in **`Shop`**, can I write code just to deserialize the **`fruits`** property and not the other properties,i.e. GSON will deserialize the remaining properties assuming they are concrete instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you should use GSON annotations they will make your life a whole lot easier.
An example:

```
public class Deal{

   @SerializedName("name")
   String name;

   @SerializedName("times")
   List<DealTime> times;

}
```

The json coming back will roughly look this:

```
{
   name:dave,
   times[
     {
      end:400,
      start:200
     },
     {
      end:30,
      start:500
     }
   ]
}
```

Then your DealTime class will have the following:

```
   public class DealTime{

       @SerializedName("end")
       int end;

       @SerializedName("start")
       int start;

    }
```

All you have to do is cast the json coming back with GSON using the Deal object. 
Hope this helps.